# How to get the values from array using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The array result shows like following

```
[ 
    { 
        _id: 56fe444d6ce2226431f5388c,
        name: 'admin',
        email: 'admin@gmail.com',
        password: '$2a$10$Wz34L5QZ6ACQIP.Q2WOJLuOSvs0aHQbSO1bhhOpiiXDOaN/AIF8U2',
        occasiontype: 'Anniversary',
        date: Mon Apr 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
        __v: 0 
    }
]
```

### node.js

```
router.post('/find-registry', function(req, res){
        var uEmail = req.body.email;

        var findUserId = function(db, callback) {
            var cursor =db.collection('users').find({email:uEmail}).toArray(function(err, docs){
                if(err){  
                    callback(new Error("Some problem"));
                } else {
                    callback(null,docs);
                } 
            });
        };

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            findUserId(db, function(err,docs) {
                db.close();
                console.log(docs);
            });
        }); 


    });
```

Here the `console.log(docs)` showing the result of array. But there i need only **name**. How do i get it? I tried like `console.log(docs[name])` but it showing undefined.

Comment: If you are only returning one document then use `.findOne()` instead.

Comment: `docs[0].name` will give you name of first json packet in array

Comment: @HemanthkumarHJ whatever happened to you man, are you alive?

Comment: i just used `docs[0].name` then i got the result. Thank u.

Comment: so why don't you accept my answer, and you're welcome :@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it like this -

```
docs[0].name
```

> You have to access the first object inside the docs array and then access the name attribute of the object.

**UPDATE**

You could simply use the **findOne()** method instead and then access the name attribute like this -

```
docs.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `docs[0].name`. `docs` is an array, and each of its entries (only one in this case) is an object with several attributes (including `name`).

Answer (score -1):

to find Each name in the array I recommend mapping to a function that finds the name of each object within the array.  This is more extensible and error tolerant than selecting the 0th element in the array if and when you're passing multiple objects in the array (which is the reason it's in an array in the first place, right?).